# What is göddertrobbe?

Tags: meaning, dialect

Here is a Hessian rhyme, probably about drinking:

> trinke mer noch en schobbe von dem schöne göddertrobbe!
>
> Hoch de Humbe, Nachbar stumbe, kurz gewunge, Humbe Pumbe!

I've had a stab at translating it:

> Drinken wir noch einen something aus dem schönen something!
>
> Hoch [mit dem] something (or possibly erhöhen wir den something?)
>
> something to do with your neighbour, some nonsense syllables?

Can anyone shed any more light on what göddertrobbe in particular is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Schobbe* is Hessian for *Schoppen* which means *pint*. *Schobbe* is also a synonym for the Äppelwoi, the Hessian apple wine.

*Göddertrobbe* is Hessian dialect and would be called *Göttertropfen* in standard German. (I am not familiar with Hessian, but I assume, it is actually *Gödderdrobbe* - with the *t* softened to *d* as well). That translates literally as *god's drop*, or *drop of the gods* into English. *Tropfen* is a very common metaphor for a precious *drink*. The composite *Göttertropfen* either means *drink fit for gods* or *drink made by gods*, or, more general, a drink which is somehow related to gods, vulgo *divine*.

*De Humbe* would be *der Humpen* (singular) or *die Humpen* (plural) in standard German, *the tankard* in English. *Hoch de Humbe!* means *Lift the tankards!*.

*stumbe* is Hessian and means *to poke*.

*gewunge* is *gewunken* in standard German, i.e. the participle of *winken*, English: *to wave*. *kurz gewunge* is a form to impress an imperative here, so it translates to *quickly wave!*

*Humbe pumbe* surely is *Humpen pumpen* in standard German, but the meaning is not very clear to me. *pumpen* means *to pump*. I assume it is a demand to empty the tankards. Then the sequence of imperatives would demand a sequence of actions: Lift your tankard, poke your neighbour, wave quickly and empty the tankard.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that "Tropfen" refers to drink here, and that the reference to gods should be read as "fit for gods".

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  I would phrase it as follows: "Gödder" (or "Götter" in standard German) is here to express high quality and high valuation. In so far it is a poetic synonym of "Super", "Mega", "Hyper", "Granaten" and so on.

Comment: Only one thing missing: "stumben" (or unsoftened "stumpen") means *to shove* or *to poke*. *Humbe Pumpe* seems to be nonsense. (If it's "Humbe pumpe", it could - IMHO - be translated as "raise/stem (your) tankards". "pumpe" would come from weightlifting)

Answer (score 5):

jonathan already explained the words, because of that I won't explain them again. Also I'm not sure if these are two separate rhymes combined together.

Well, at least the second one is quite common. There is also a Hessian carnival society called "Sackschdoahogger" and it's like their official drinking motto. This is how they explain it:

> Hoch de Humbe
>
> Nochber stumbe
>
> korz gewunke
>
> Humbe bumbe

is their official toast when drinking alcohol.

And this is what to do ([link](http://www.sackschdoahogger.de/2017/07/04/hoch-de-humbe/))

> Get a glas full of alcohol
>
> Lift the glas (hoch de Humbe),
>
> nudge your neighbor (softly) (Nochber stumbe),
>
> wave at everybody in the room (korz gewunke)
>
> drink from your glas (Humbe bumbe). Empty it, if possible.

And if you still don't know what to do: [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdfcUcJSVW4)

Of course a Humbe/Humpen is more like a tankard than a glass but well ... we live in modern times.

Comment: Ah, the video makes clear that it is _Nachbar gstumbe_! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is a Hessian toast. jonathan.scholbach has translated it in his answer. "Göttertropfen" refers to Hessian apple cider whose sophisticated taste is revealed not to many foreigners ;-)

Here is an extended version of the second line:

> Hoch de Humpe, kurz gewunke,  Nachbar stumbe, Humbe pumbe, in diesem Sinne
>   ab in die Rinne.

For another extended variant see https://www.stupidedia.org/stupi/Trinkspruch .

And here is a photo from December 24, 2007. It shows an advertisement of a cider-press house in a subway station in Frankfurt.

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure it was that very sign that inspired the question! It's on the S6 line, isn't it

Comment: Yes, it's the S-Bahn station "Hauptwache" (lines S1 -  S9).